# Creating multiple custom revision table in envers

Tags: java, audit, hibernate-envers

I need a help.

I was able to setup envers in my project with custom revision entity. But, right now the requirement is that I need to create a separate revision table for User table ( as there as millions of user and for a better performance we dont wanna to put all the audited data in one table)

Is it possible in hiberate-envers to create a separate revision table for a particular entity?

More about hibernate envers, please have a look at the link:

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not consider using database table partitions instead?  Databases which offer partitioning basically store the table across different files, often different disks, allowing for increased read/write performance while the users of the database still see it as a single contiguous table.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only have a single revision entity per Hibernate configuration (`SessionFactory`/`EntityManagerFactory`).

Comment: It would have been so perfect having a revinfo table for each audited entity